# linear interpolation with grided data in python

Tags: python, linear-interpolation

I've a gridded weather data set which have a dimension  33 X 77 X 77. The first dimension is time and rest are Lat and Lon respectively. I need to interpolate (linear or nearest neighbour) the data to different points (lat&lon) for each time and write it into a csv file. I've used interp2d function from scipy and it is successful for one time step. As I've many locations I don't want to  loop over time.

below shown is the piece of code that I wrote, Can any one suggest a better method to accomplish the task?

```
import sys ; import numpy as np ; import scipy as sp ; from scipy.interpolate import interp2d ;import datetime ; import time ; import pygrib as pg ; 
grb_f=pg.open('20150331/gfs.20150331.grb2')  lat=tmp[0].data(lat1=4,lat2=42,lon1=64,lon2=102)[1] ; lat=lat[:,0]; 
lon=tmp[0].data(lat1=4,lat2=42,lon1=64,lon2=102)[2] ; lon=lon[0,:] ; 
temp=np.empty((0,lon.shape[0]))
for i in range(0,tmp.shape[0]):
    dat=tmp[i].data(lat1=4,lat2=42,lon1=64,lon2=102)
    temp=np.concatenate([temp,dat[0]-273.15],axis=0)
temp1=temp.reshape(tmp.shape[0],lat.shape[0],lon.shape[0])
x=77 ; y=28 #(many points) 
f=interp2d(lon,lat, temp1[0,:,:],kind='linear',copy=False,bounds_error=True ) ; Z=f(x,y)
```

EDIT ::

Instead of making a 3D matrix, I appended  the data in vertically and made data matrix of size 2541 X 77 and lat and lon of size 2541 X 1. the interp2d function gives Invalid length Error.

```
f=interp2d(lon,lat, temp1[0,:,:],kind='linear',copy=False,bounds_error=True )
```

> "Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid")

ValueError: Invalid length for input z for non rectangular grid

length of my x,y,z matrix are same (2541,2541,2541). Then why did it throw an Error? 
Could any one explain ? Your help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Processing of time series is very easy with [RedBlackPy](https://intuitionengineeringteam.github.io/RedBlackPy/).

```
 import datetime as dt
 import redblackpy as rb

 index = [dt.date(2018,1,1), dt.date(2018,1,3), dt.date(2018,1,5)]
 lat = [10.0, 30.0, 50.0]
 # create Series object
 lat_series = rb.Series(index=index, values=lat, dtype='float32',
                        interpolate='linear')
 # Now you can access at any key using linear interpolation
 # Interpolation does not create new items in Series
 # It uses neighbours to calculate value inplace when you call getitem
 print(lat_series[dt.date(2018,1,2)]) #prints 20
```

So, if you want to just write interpolated values to csv file, you can iterate over list of needed keys and call getitem of Series object then put value to file:

```
 # generator for dates range
 def date_range(start, stop, step=dt.timedelta(1)):

     it = start - step

     while it < step:
         it += step
         yield it

 #------------------------------------------------
 # create list for keeping output strings
 out_data = []    
 # create output file
 out_file = open('data.csv', 'w')
 # add head for output table
 out_data.append('Time,Lat\n')

 for date in date_range(dt.date(2018,1,1), dt.date(2018,1,5)):
     out_data.append( '{:},{:}\n'.format(date, lat_series[date]) )

 # write output Series
 out_file.writelines(out_data)
 out_file.close()
```

By the same way you can add to your processing Lon data.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same lat and lon for each time could you do it using slices and a manual interpolation. So if you want a 1D array of values at lat = 4.875, lon = 8.4 (obviously you would need to scale to match your actual spacing)

```
b = a[:,4:6, 8:10]
c = ((b[:,0,0] * 0.125 + b[:,0,1] * 0.875) * 0.6 + ((b[:,1,0] * 0.125 + b[:,1,1] * 0.875) * 0.4)
```

obviously you could do it all in one line but it would be even uglier

EDIT to allow variable lat and lon at each time period.

```
lat = np.linspace(55.0, 75.0, 33)
lon = np.linspace(1.0, 25.0, 33)
data = np.linspace(18.0, 25.0, 33 * 77 * 77).reshape(33, 77, 77)

# NB for simplicity I map 0-360 and 0-180 rather than -180+180
# also need to ensure values on grid lines or edges work ok
lat_frac = lat * 77.0 / 360.0
lat_fr = np.floor(lat_frac).astype(int)
lat_to = lat_fr + 1
lat_frac -= lat_fr

lon_frac = lon * 77.0 / 180.0
lon_fr = np.floor(lon_frac).astype(int)
lon_to = lon_fr + 1
lon_frac -= lon_fr

data_interp = ((data[:,lat_fr,lon_fr] * (1.0 - lat_frac) +
                data[:,lat_fr,lon_to] * lat_frac) * (1.0 - lon_frac) +
               (data[:,lat_to,lon_fr] * (1.0 - lat_frac) +
                data[:,lat_to,lon_to] * lat_frac) * lon_frac)
```

Comment: No, my lat and lon are not same. Rather the points spans around the globe. so slicing is not a possible option. I need a method,  free from loops.

Comment: thinking about it, you can use numpy advanced indexing with arrays of integers instead of 4,6,8,10 and arrays of floats instead of 0.125, 0.875 etc. I will sketch out a more detailed answer but if lat1=[4,4,5,5,5,.. lat2=[5,5,6,6,.. lon1=[8,9,10,10... lon2=[9,10,11,11.. then b=a[:,[lat1,lat2],[lon1,lon2]]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an "interpolator" object once, and use it to sequentially query just the specific points you need, you could take a loot at the [`scipy.interpolate.Rbf`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html) module:

> "A class for radial basis function approximation/interpolation of n-dimensional scattered data."

Where `n-dimensional` would work for your data if you adjust ratio between temporal and spatial dimensions, and `scattered` meaning you can also use it for regular/uniform data.